# Visual Studio code to manipulate MySql Data

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

So I am using Visual Studios 2015 and MySQL 5.7.

First, I have a table called "items" which contain the following columns and rows:

```
BranchNo itemNo itemName   Qty Pkey
1        1      Chicken    99  11
1        2      Coke       99  12
1        3      Applie Pie 99  13
```

Then I have another table called "setmeal" which uses the Pkey (itemNo in "setmeal" table) of table "items":

```
setmealno  branchno  itemNo  Name              Price  SetMealID   entryNo
1          1         11      1pc Fried Chicken 69     11          1
1          1         12      1pc Fried Chicken 69     11          2
2          1         13      Apple Pie Single  50     12          3
3          1         12      Coke Drink        20     13          4
```

Basically what table "setmeal" does is, is if there are 2 itemNo's with same "SetMealID", then they belong to the same set.

Then I have a "cart" which consists of (assuming I ordered):

```
TransactionNo  UserNo  SetMealNo  Name              Price  Date   BranchNo
1              1       11         1pc Fried Chicken 69     2015   1
```

So what I want to do in Visual Studios (2015) is whatever you put in the "cart", there's a code that's automatically going to deduct 1 in "Qty" in table "items" if the SetmealNo is the same with table "setmeal".

I need a code in visual studios to successfully deduct 1 from Qty whenever the conditions above are met.

Although, I think joining the 3 tables is the first step. (Although I also have no idea how to do it in MySQL Select Statements)

EDIT: I found how to merge the 3 tables

```
SELECT s.setmealid, t.setmealNo, i.pKey, s.itemNo, i.qty 
FROM items i, setmeal s, cart t
WHERE s.itemNo = i.pKey and t.setmealno != 0
AND s.setmealID = t.setmealNo
AND t.transactionNo = '" & Form2.TextBoxTransNo.Text & "';
```

It Produces this table

```
setmealid  setmealNo  pKey  itemNo  qty
11         11         11    11      99
11         11         12    12      99
```

All that's left is a Visual Studios code to deduct from "qty" although I do not know how to do it.

Comment: And what's the question here?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought I was being clear. Edited the original post